# Help on 74LS47 and 7 segment diode

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I'm quite new to electronic chips and I'm trying out my first project which is a requirement for school.

My problem is that my circuit doesn't light up.

here is the image of my project.[image]

I need help due to me being a beginner and not having any chip circuitry knowledge. Sorry if I bother you.

Comment: Please post the schematic you used to build the circuit. I don't really feel like tracing all your wires to figure it out for myself =P

Comment: 1 - your switch is wired wrong, 2 - pin 16 goes directly to +5, 3 - you need resistors on your outputs unless the display incorporates them, 4 - you have not identified your display.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from datasheet 74LS47 lights each segment by connecting it to 0. Therefore you need a "common anode" type 7-segment. And the common pin (pins 3 and 8 from the 7 segment) must be connected to VCC (positive rail).

As I can see from your picture, the common pin of the 7-segment is grounded. Therefore it won't work even if it is a common anode type. With a tester you can quickly check if it is common anode or common cathode.

To check if it is common anode, put the tester at "diode check mode" and  place the red probe in one of the common pins (3 or 8) and with the black probe touch the other pins to see if they light up; in such a case you have a "common anode" type (the proper to use with a 7447). If it fails, swap black and red probes roles, and if they now light up you have a "common cathode" type (you would need then a 7448 and not a 7447).

Comment: Are you sure about needing a common anode display? Pretty sure the 74LS47 requires a common cathode one....?

Comment: @derstrom8, yes, I'm quite sure! 7447 works with CA, while 7448 works with CC.

Comment: Checking my sources....

Comment: You are quite correct! My apologies--I have deleted my comment which had an incorrect schematic

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing quite a few issues already. First of all, why is pin 16 (VCC) connected through a resistor? Is the 7-segment display CA or CC?

Use this schematic for reference:

[7447 circuit http://www.neoembedded.com/media/wysiwyg/7447_ckt.gif](http://www.neoembedded.com/media/wysiwyg/7447_ckt.gif)

Make sure you're powering from 5 volts. The display MUST be CA in order to work with the 74LS47. The switches need to be connected between A, B, C, and D and ground, so that you connect those pins to ground when the switches are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Without a circuit diagram showing what you intend to do I'm making some guesses, there are a number of clear problems with your circuit:

1. Each segment of your display should have a resistor connecting it to the LS47 driver IC to control the current drawn by the display. You just have wires.
2. Why the resistor from pin-16 of the LS47? That should be wired directly to your supply.
3. Your DIP-switch needs to have one side wired directly to either 'ground' (or supply), and the other side is where you connect to the LS47. This side should also have pullup resistors (or pulldowns)
4. The LS47 has open-collector outputs and is therefore is intended to drive a common-anode display (this display has its 'common' pin connected to your supply), but yours appears to be a common-cathode (judging solely by the way you've connected its common to ground)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a resistor between the 74LS47's Vcc pin and the positive supply.

74LS inputs source current, and you need to draw about 0.8 mA from the input to get it below 0.8 volts to be recognized as a low.  Therefore, it is common to connect the switches between the input pins and Ground, with a pull-up resistor from the input pin to the positive supply, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGLrdg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>